# Install MOLDEN in MACOS Big Surf

Tags: software

I'm trying to install Molden in a MACOS Bigsurf.

The steps that I followed:

0. Install the compilers, gfortran,libraries, etc.
1. extract the source from molden page.
2. open the molden5.8 directory and from terminal run "make all".

But, in step 2 I get the following message:

Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/REAL(4)).
molden.f:6495:28:

6495 |              call parptr(16,fdum,fdum,idum)
|                            1
......
8594 |       call parptr(1,freq,fdum,idum)
|                    2
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/REAL(4)).
make: *** [molden.o] Error 1

what is wrong?
what can I do?

Comment: This question is not on topic here, since it is not about chemistry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are Molden precompiled binaries for OS X.  Here is a page that shows you how to acquire molden binaries.
https://www.macinchem.org/blog/files/7a5f03265cc78741fb3cc2a86c54f41e-377.php 
You ftp the server as a guest and download the most recent binary.  After you ftp in, it will open a virtual drive and you can copy it right to your Desktop.  I just tried it on Catalina and it worked right out of the box.